# Unable to send email from asp.net form

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have created a form to send email to an email account and used the following code.

```
       Dim client As New SmtpClient()
        Dim emailmessage As New MailMessage()

        Dim emailfrom As New MailAddress(txtEmail.Text)

        emailmessage.Subject = "Web Submission"
        emailmessage.Body = "Web submission received from " & txtName.Text & ". Phone no: "     & txtPhone.Text & "."
        client.Host = "localhost"
        client.Port = 25
        emailmessage.From = emailfrom
        emailmessage.To.Add("info@test.com")

        client.Send(emailmessage)
        lblMessage.Text = "Thank you, we will contact you soon"
```

I am using IIS express to run my project. I know that IIS express doesnt support smtp, if I am correct. But if the code is correct it should run properly. Anyway I published my site through .net publish tool to my godaddy account. when I try to send email from the form I am getting the following error message.

Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for "info@test.com"

```
Dim msg As New MailMessage()
        msg.To = "test@gmail.com"
        msg.From = "test@gmail.com"
        msg.Subject = "test"
        'msg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html
        msg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text
        msg.Body = "hi"

        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost"

        SmtpMail.Send(msg)
        lblMessage.Text = "An Email has been send to " & "test@gmail.com"
```

I tried the above code and still its not working. I just cant figure out what I am doing wroong here. I remember I used got this working sometime back. But I cant remember how.

Comment: It looks like you need to configure your mailserver.

Comment: I believe you have configured your Virtual Smtp Server to work for localhost also can you try with the line SmtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = True before Send(msg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your missing SmtpServer Credentials

```
        client.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password")
```

If not this then please configure your smtp virtual server as shown in example http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2006/04/05/using-localhost-as-mailserver-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-for-xxx/

Comment: Thanks. What happens if the user changes the password?

Comment: If i understood you correctly the credentials can be kept in config like shown in scott's example http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx so when ever password changes this config will need to be updated instead rebuilding code