# Want to send automatic mail from asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send an automatic mail from my asp.net website whenever a person will click submit button to enter some value. I have created some codes in C#. It's not showing any error, but also not sending any mail. I am using ip address of the mail server of the organization in the network credential. I am not sure how to provide password for the email address I am using to send mail. I am sharing my code with you.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.ComponentModel;// for backgroundworker class
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading;

public partial class Contact : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void LoginView1_ViewChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "dbo.Procedure";

            command.Parameters.Add("@name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("email", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("sub", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sub.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("message", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = message.Text;

            string from = "info@xxx.com";
            string to = "abc@xxx.com";
            string mailSubject = sub.Text.ToString();
            string mailBody = message.Text.ToString(); 
            MailMessage mess = new MailMessage(from, to, mailSubject, mailBody);
            mess.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient("//xxx.xxx.x.x/", 25); //Server ip & port
            emailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            //System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
            //emailClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
            //emailClient.Send(mess);

           // emailClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

            try
            {
                emailClient.Send(mess);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateTestMessage1(): {0}",
                      ex.ToString());
            }

            command.Connection = connn;
            connn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connn.Close();
        }
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        email.Text = "";
        sub.Text = "";
        message.Text = "";
        lblmsg.Text = "Data entered successfully!!! Thank You for contacting us! We will get back to you as soon as possible.";
        //Response.Write("Submitted Succesfully");
        Response.Redirect("~/XX.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try some lower level debugging to validate your SMTP settings with telnet: http://damonparker.org/blog/2005/09/12/debugging-popimapsmtp-with-telnet/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=debugging-popimapsmtp-with-telnet

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to stop using default credentials

```
emailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

and add

```
emailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourusername", "yourpassword");
```

to use your own credentials as most SMTP servers now block anonymous relay in order to stop SPAM.

Comment: I would be particularly hesitant about putting my password into the code. I agree with not using the DefaultCredentials, but would specify `emailClient.Credentials=System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` and then ensure that the identity of the application pool is configured to a user who can authenticate against the SMTP server.

Comment: @DuncanHowe thats a very good point, alternativly if you cannot set the application pool details to match (ie its on a shared platform) I would suggest putting it in web.config and then encrypting web.config  http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/06/11/encrypting-the-web-config-file.aspx

Comment: I don't want to put password in the code. Could you please suggest me how to do it in web.config? I have mention my network host there. I have to provide my network user and password there, right? where should I put my email password? I am new so may be asking stupid questions. Thanks all.

Comment: Thanks. I tried as per what you mentioned. But still no success. Don't I have to put username and password for specific email address from which I am trying to send mail?

Comment: @MSI yes - replace the yourusername and yourpassword with your specific SMTP login credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Please put the configuration in your application’s web.config file. Here is an example of how to configure it:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="test@test.com">
        <network host="smtpserver1" port="25" userName="StackOverFlow" password="HatSoft" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

I have already answered a similar query at [Unable to send email from asp.net form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285338/unable-to-send-email-from-asp-net-form/11285457#11285457)

Comment: Is it ok if I put ip address of the server in network host other than putting server name?

Comment: Yes you can and I don't see any reason of failure for it

Comment: For username and Password here, should I put server username and password or my email address username and password. really new to this stuff, thanks for all your help.

Comment: username & password must the one given that will authenticate the SMTP server and is given to you by your administrator

Comment: Thanks. I am actually trying that. Do I have to put my email's username and password anywhere in the code? If yes, where?

Comment: email can go here <smtp from="test@test.com"> and the useranem & password can go userName="StackOverFlow" password="HatSoft" please try this and let me the result

Comment: No Success yet. My we.config now looks like: <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp from="xxx@xxx.com">
                <network host="\\xxx.xxx.x.x\" port="25" password="xxx" userName="xxx" defaultCredentials="true"/>
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13487/discussion-between-hatsoft-and-msi)

Comment: and my code behind looks like: string from = "xxx@xxx.com";
            string to = "xxx@gmail.com";
            string mailSubject = sub.Text.ToString();
            string mailBody = message.Text.ToString(); 
            MailMessage mess = new MailMessage(from, to, mailSubject, mailBody);
            mess.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient("//xxx.xxx.x.x/", 25);
            emailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            emailClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;